# fuzzy and exact match of two databases

Tags: r, purrr, parallel.foreach, fuzzyjoin, furrr

I have two databases.  The first one has about 70k rows with 3 columns.  the second one has 790k rows with 2 columns.  Both databases have a common variable `grantee_name`.  I want to match each row of the first database to one or more rows of the second database based on this `grantee_name`.  Note that `merge` will not work because the `grantee_name` do not match perfectly.  There are different spellings etc.  So, I am using the `fuzzyjoin` package and trying the following:

```
library("haven"); library("fuzzyjoin"); library("dplyr")
forfuzzy<-read_dta("/path/forfuzzy.dta")
filings <- read_dta ("/path/filings.dta")
> head(forfuzzy)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  grantee_name                 grantee_city grantee_state
  <chr>                        <chr>        <chr>        
1 (ICS)2 MAINE CHAPTER         CLEARWATER   FL           
2 (SUFFOLK COUNTY) VANDERBILT~ CENTERPORT   NY           
3 1 VOICE TREKKING A FUND OF ~ WESTMINSTER  MD           
4 10 CAN                       NEWBERRY     FL           
5 10 THOUSAND WINDOWS          LIVERMORE    CA           
6 100 BLACK MEN IN CHICAGO INC CHICAGO      IL   
... 7 - 70000 rows to go

> head(filings)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  grantee_name                       ein 
  <chr>                             <dbl>               
1 ICS-2 MAINE CHAPTER              123456             
2 SUFFOLK COUNTY VANDERBILT        654321            
3 VOICE TREKKING A FUND OF VOICES  789456            
4 10 CAN                           654987               
5 10 THOUSAND MUSKETEERS INC       789123               
6 100 BLACK MEN IN HOUSTON INC     987321      

rows 7-790000 omitted for brevity
```

The above examples are clear enough to provide some good matches and some not-so-good matches.  Note that, for example, `10 THOUSAND WINDOWS` will match best with `10 THOUSAND MUSKETEERS INC` but it does not mean it is a good match.  There will be a better match somewhere in the `filings` data (not shown above).  That does not matter at this stage.

So, I have tried the following:

```
df<-as.data.frame(stringdist_inner_join(forfuzzy, filings, by="grantee_name", method="jw", p=0.1, max_dist=0.1, distance_col="distance"))
```

Totally new to R.  This is resulting in an error:
`cannot allocate vector of size 375GB` (with the big database of course).  A sample of 100 rows from `forfuzzy` always works.  So, I thought of iterating over a list of 100 rows at a time.

I have tried the following:

```
n=100
lst = split(forfuzzy, cumsum((1:nrow(forfuzzy)-1)%%n==0))

df<-as.data.frame(lapply(lst, function(df_)
{
(stringdist_inner_join(df_, filings, by="grantee_name", method="jw", p=0.1, max_dist=0.1, distance_col="distance", nthread = getOption("sd_num_thread")))
}
)%>% bind_rows)
```

I have also tried the above with `mclapply` instead of `lapply`.  Same error happens even though I have tried a high-performance cluster setting 3 CPUs, each with 480G of memory and using `mclapply` with the option `mc.cores=3`.  Perhaps a `foreach` command could help, but I have no idea how to implement it.

I have been advised to use the `purrr` and `repurrrsive` packages, so I try the following:

```
purrr::map(lst, ~stringdist_inner_join(., filings, by="grantee_name", method="jw", p=0.1, max_dist=0.1, distance_col="distance", nthread = getOption("sd_num_thread")))
```

This seems to be working, after a novice error in the `by=grantee_name` statement.  However, it is taking forever and I am not sure it will work.  A sample list in `forfuzzy` of 100 rows, with `n=10` (so 10 lists with 10 rows each) has been running for 50 minutes, and still no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you split (with `base::split` or `dplyr::group_split`) your uniquegrantees data frame into a list of data frames, then you can call `purrr::map` on the list. (`map` is pretty much `lapply`)

`purrr::map(list_of_dfs, ~stringdist_inner_join(., filings, by="grantee_name", method="jw", p=0.1, max_dist=0.1, distance_col="distance"))`

Your result will be a list of data frames each fuzzyjoined with filings. You can then call `bind_rows` (or you could do `map_dfr`) to get all the results in the same data frame again.

See [R - Splitting a large dataframe into several smaller dateframes, performing fuzzyjoin on each one and outputting to a single dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64369240/r-splitting-a-large-dataframe-into-several-smaller-dateframes-performing-fuzz/64440118#64440118)

Comment: It's hard to tell where your error is coming from. Please create a reproducible example and edit your question. You can provide samples of your data with head() and dput()

Comment: try reducing your data as small as possible (one row to match, 2 data frames in list) and see what happens

Comment: cannot get it to work faster.  On HPC systems, i get the error "large vectors not supported yet...".  That said, barring the slow speed, it works.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: you can also try adjusting the max_dist and p parameters to restrict the results to "good matches" or play around with the method="jw". This page explains the different methods possible: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringdist/versions/0.9.4.6/topics/stringdist-metrics

Comment: Did upvote Arthur, but I need a higher rep to make it count.  The code is running on Windows (but very finicky) but not on a HPC cluster.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549055/long-vectors-stringdist-package-r

Comment: I see. Good luck - not sure how to help with that

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used foreach before but maybe the variable x is already the individual rows of zz1?

Have you tried:

`stringdist_inner_join(x, zz2, by="grantee_name", method="jw", p=0.1, max_dist=0.1, distance_col="distance")`

?

Comment: Thanks ArthurI have tried it.  Error message `Error in as.data.frame(x) : object 'x' not found`

Comment: Is there a possibility I can use lapply or mclapply?  If so, how would I change the above?  Sorry: novice in R here.

Comment: it looks like you want to return(as.data.frame(the whole data frame, not individual "x"))

Comment: mclapply could help but i'm not familiar with it.

Comment: see my other answer for using map (which is basically lapply)